# How can I get dictionary data from python file to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, odoo

I want to use data from back-end to front-end by JavaScript. In this case, I tried to take data from back-end by python.

I wrote this code in Python:

```
pb_categories = {
    'motherboard': motherboard.id,
    'processor': processor.id,
    'power_supply': power_supply.id
    }
pb_categories_json = json.dumps(pb_categories)
return request.render("module.template_id", {'pb_categories_json': (pb_categories_json)})
```

I've wrote js code"

```
function loadData(pb_categories_json) {
    var pbCategories = JSON.parse(pb_categories_json);
    console.log("All Called Category:" + pbCategories);
      }
```

Why am I not getting data in the `pbCategories` variable?

Comment: show the template

Comment: I am just generating a link by dictionary item id like this  

`<a href="/shop/category/' +pbCategories.motherboard +'" class="btn btn-secondary choose_button col-md-1">Choose</a>').appendTo($pbItemDiv);
`

Everything I'm doing on js file

Comment: Your code it's not reproducible, better share a link to your module so we could help you better